# Using .loc on just second index in multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiindex dataframe that looks like this:

```
                value
year    name                
1921    Ah      40     
1921    Ai      90      
1922    Ah      100     
1922    Ai      7
```

in which `year` and `name` are the indices. I want to select every row where the name `Ai` appears. I have tried `df.loc[(:,'Ai')]` and `df.loc['Ai']` but both give errors. How do I index only using the name column?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would use [`.xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) on the first level of your multiindex (note: `level=1` refers to the "second" index (`name`) because of python's zero indexing: level 0 is `year` in your case):

```
df.xs('Ai', level=1, drop_level=False)
# or
df.xs('Ai', level='name', drop_level=False)

           value
year name       
1921 Ai       90
1922 Ai        7
```

Comment: All good answers but this is the most straightforward solution I think. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 40):

@sacul has the most idiomatic answer, but here are a few alternatives.

#### `MultiIndex.get_level_values`

```
df[df.index.get_level_values('name') == 'Ai']

           value
year name       
1921 Ai       90
1922 Ai        7
```

---

#### `DataFrame.query`

```
df.query('name == "Ai"')

           value
year name       
1921 Ai       90
1922 Ai        7
```

---

#### `DataFrame.loc(axis=0)` with `pd.IndexSlice`

Similar to @liliscent's answer, but does not need the trailing `:` if you specify `axis=0`.

```
df.loc(axis=0)[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'Ai']]

           value
year name       
1921 Ai       90
1922 Ai        7
```

Comment: Faster, you deserve +1

Comment: I didn't know you could use `query()` with row multi-index. I find this one to be the most intuitive syntax of all the answers.

Answer (score 14):

If you prefer `loc`, you can use:

```
In [245]: df.loc[(slice(None), 'Ai'), :]
     ...: 
Out[245]: 
           value
year name       
1921 Ai       90
1922 Ai        7
```

Comment: Good answer, this is equivalent to `df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 'Ai'], :]`.

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks.

Comment: Documented in [using slicers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers) and [index slice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html#pandas-indexslice).