# iloc'ing one level of a multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiindex dataframe, something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['mike', 'matt', 'dave', 'frank', 'larry'], range(10)]))
df['foo']="bar"
df.index.names=['people', 'socket']
```

What I'd like to do is iloc-slice all the rows associated with the first three people in the index.  IE: retrieve all the rows where `people` is either `matt` `mike` or `dave`.

[As far as I can tell](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15228), though, this is not at all supported by pandas. Saw some gross levels-related hacks, but they didn't even work.  `get_level_values(0)` doesn't give distinct level values,  and `levels()` returns an unsorted `frozenset`.

edit:  I should have said  that `.loc`-based solutions won't work for me.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/50414126/2641825

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is get first uniqe values of first level, indexing and select by `loc`:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(0).unique()[:3]]
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.index.get_level_values(0).unique()[:3])
Index(['mike', 'matt', 'dave'], dtype='object', name='people')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['mike', 'matt', 'dave', 'frank', 'larry'], range(10)], names=['people', 'socket']))
df['foo']="bar"
df.index.names=['people', 'socket']
# get rows
select_rows = df.loc[['mike', 'matt', 'dave']]
```

Output:

```
people socket     
mike   0       bar
       1       bar
       2       bar
       3       bar
       4       bar
       5       bar
       6       bar
       7       bar
       8       bar
       9       bar
matt   0       bar
       1       bar
       2       bar
       3       bar
       4       bar
       5       bar
       6       bar
       7       bar
       8       bar
       9       bar
dave   0       bar
       1       bar
       2       bar
       3       bar
       4       bar
       5       bar
       6       bar
       7       bar
       8       bar
       9       bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values(0)
     .isin({'matt','mike','dave'})]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [df.xs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html)()

> "This method takes a key argument to select data at a particular level of a MultiIndex."

Reusing your example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['mike', 'matt', 'dave', 'frank', 'larry'], range(10)], names=['people', 'socket']))
df['foo']="bar"
df.index.names=['people', 'socket']


In [60]: df.xs("mike", level="people")
Out[60]:
        foo
socket
0       bar
1       bar
2       bar
3       bar
4       bar
5       bar
6       bar
7       bar
8       bar
9       bar

In [61]: df.xs(7, level="socket")
Out[61]:
        foo
people
mike    bar
matt    bar
dave    bar
frank   bar
larry   bar
```